# Last Inserted ID using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I already tried:-

`$last_id = $stmt->lastInsertId();`

But still its not returning string nor data, its just white blank page, any idea on how to return last id using **PDO** ?

**PHP**

```
public function createTrip($trip_name,$trip_cost,$trip_start,$trip_end,$trip_location,$trip_description)
{
    try
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO trips(trip_name,trip_cost,trip_start,trip_end,trip_location,trip_description) 
                                                   VALUES(:trip_name,:trip_cost,:trip_start,:trip_end,:trip_location,:trip_description)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":trip_name", $trip_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":trip_cost", $trip_cost);
        $stmt->bindparam(":trip_start", $trip_start);
        $stmt->bindparam(":trip_end", $trip_end);
        $stmt->bindparam(":trip_location", $trip_location);
        $stmt->bindparam(":trip_description", $trip_description);

        $stmt->execute();   
        $last_id = $stmt->lastInsertId();

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

HTML

```
 $trip = new TRIP();
 $trip>createTrip($trip_name,$trip_cost,$trip_start,$trip_end,$trip_location,$trip_description);
```

Comment: instead of `return $stmt;`  i think you have to do `return $last_id;` and then `echo $last_id =$trip>createTrip($trip_name,$trip_cost,$trip_start,$trip_end,$trip_location,$trip_description);`

Comment: you're not returning any ids in your function `return $stmt;`, its not even assigned into anything yet `$trip>createTrip(`

Comment: Martney please check the answers and if any-one is correct mark and up-vote that answer. if others are useful too, then up-vote them too.thanks

Comment: Uhm... syntax error? Missing `-` in `$trip>createTrip...`?

Comment: people are not responding. waste of time and effort.

Comment: Hi I already find a way to make it happen, yes I think this is a duplicate post kindly delete this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$last_id = $this->conn->lastInsertId();

return $last_id;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php